# Swift: WKWebView add javascript interface like Android

Tags: android, swift, webview

I have a page that I want to display in a webview with dynamic content.

On Android I can do it simple by interface, here is the interface:

```
class WebAppInterface (val context: Context, val userId: Long, val  type: String) {
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun getId(): Long {
        return userId
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    fun getBaseUrl(): String{
       return Configuration.getInstance().userConfig.getStoredBaseUrl();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    fun getGetStatType(): String{
       return type;
    }
}
```

`webview.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(this.applicationContext, id, statisticsType!! ), "android")`

How can I do the same thing on iOS, after my search I got this:

```
let contentController = WKUserContentController()
        contentController.add(self, name: "android") // -> Set a listener

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController = contentController

        let scriptString = "????? What write ir?"
        let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptString, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
        config.userContentController.addUserScript(script)

        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
```

And the delegate method:

```
 func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print(message)
}
```

In the delegate method it does not print when it arrives on the keyword android? Why? Did I misunderstand the operation?
Here is some of my js code that works well with the androidInterface

```
function getSteps() {
    const url = android.getBaseUrl() + 'patient/' + android.getId() + '/statistics/steps?from=' + from + '&to=' + to;
    Http.open("GET", url);
    Http.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + android.getToken())
    Http.send();
}
```

How can I inject the values into the "android" js, as I did on android.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51998861/wkscriptmessagehandler-wont-listen-to-onclick-or-click-event-on-a-button-el

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved the probleme by inject the android object created manually like this:

```
let scriptString = """
                       var android = {
                            getGetStatType: function() {
                                return 'sleep';
                            },
                            getId: function() {
                                return 98;
                            },
                            getBaseUrl: function() {
                                return 'baseUrl';
                            },
                            getToken: function() {
                                return 'myToken';
                            }
                       };
                       """
    let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptString, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    config.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not possible to call swift method from javascript synchronously to get value. Only one possible way is asynchronous way using WKUserContentController. In your case you were lucky that values are not dynamic. It is not usable for example to get some value which changes over time e.g. GPS location.

SWIFT

```
webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "someName")

func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print(message.name, message.body)
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("window.asyncResponseFromIos(123)")
}
```

JS

```
window.webkit.messageHandlers.someName.postMessage("data")
```

So it is not possible to have universal synchronous interface in JS for android and ios. That is why Im going to make JS interface based on promises. In JS I will get value from android/ios by calling e.g. `var value = await window.mobileAppInterface.get("someKey", "somePayload")` The aim is to have universal javascript interface independent on app platform.